# SendKeys.SendWait() não está funcionando em determinado aplicativo

Tags: .net, vb.net

Estou com um software para o meu tcc, no qual estou emulando o pressionamento de uma tecla utilizando o `SendKeys.SendWait("{F12}")`.

Criei os metodos e tudo certinho e fui testar, porém no aplicativo que eu preciso que ele funcione, ele não esta funcionando... testei no browser, no word e o comando funciona, mas nesse software não.

Vou deixar meu código e o software que estou tentando usar.

A linguagem que estou utilizando é VB.Net

```
Private Sub EmulaPressionamentoTecla()
    SendKeys.SendWait("{F12}")
End Sub
```

O software que estou precisando que funcione é o ACAT, mesmo software que o Stephen Hawking usava para se comunicar...

https://github.com/intel/acat

Comment: Você consegue detalhar mais o seu cenário? como está a comunicação com esse outro software e onde o seu método está sendo chamado? O problema é apenas com o F12 ou qualquer comando?

Comment: Estou fazendo a comunicação por socket, eu tenho um app no android que é client que fica mandando 0 e 1 para o servidor, quando chega 1, o servidor entender que deve ser emulado o pressionamento da tecla. Acredito que o problema deva ser apenas alguma coisa de delay em função desse software que eu preciso que ele funcione, pois os testes nos demais softwares deram certo...

Comment: Estou fazendo esse projeto, pois é para uma mulher, que perdeu seus movimentos em função de um acidente, e a unica coisa que ele consegue mexer no seu corpo, é o seu polegar, por isso estou fazendo desta forma.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente colocar no construtor (New) ou no evento (Load) a seguinte função:

```
Me.KeyPreview = True
```

Nesse caso ele irá detectar o pressionamento de alguma tecla e você precisa desenvolver a rotina que selcionará qual a tecla ou combinação de teclas você quer que alguma rotina dispare.

```
Private Sub GUI_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then

        'Faz alguma coisa

    End If

End Sub
```